# Как исправить Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed?

Tags: yii2

собственно лучше всего выложу лог

```
in /var/www/cremea.lc/vendor/omnilight/yii2-shopping-cart/ShoppingCart.php
    public function getSerialized()
    {
        return serialize($this->_positions);//ошибка здесь
    }

 in /var/www/cremea.lc/vendor/omnilight/yii2-shopping-cart/ShoppingCart.php at line 120 – serialize(['a:2:{s:2:"id";i:96;s:6:"volume";s:8:"300 гр";}' => frontend\models\CartPosition]) 
    public function getSerialized()
    {
        return serialize($this->_positions);//ошибка здесь
    }

 in /var/www/cremea.lc/vendor/omnilight/yii2-shopping-cart/ShoppingCart.php at line 79 – yz\shoppingcart\ShoppingCart::getSerialized() 
    public function saveToSession()
    {
        $this->session = Instance::ensure($this->session, Session::className());
        $this->session[$this->cartId] = $this->getSerialized();// ошибка здесь
    }

 in /var/www/cremea.lc/frontend/widgets/cart/Cart.php at line 38 – yz\shoppingcart\ShoppingCart::put(frontend\models\CartPosition, 1) 
            $prise= Price::find()->where("price=".$post['Carts']['price'])->andWhere("product_id=".$post['productId'])->one();
            $prises=$prise->price;
            $volume=$prise->volume;
            $country=$prise->countryid;
            $cartPosition = new CartPosition($position->id, $prises, $country, $volume);
            if ($position) {
                \Yii::$app->cart->put($cartPosition, 1);//ошибка здесь
```

где я допустил ошибку не подскажите и в чем она ?

Comment: Вам прямо пишут, чт оу вас где-то функция-замыкание (в _positions), которую вы пытаетесь засериализовать

Comment: @etki вот я и не могу понять где

Comment: ну, вы же не ожидаете, что мы магическим образом отсюда укажем на строчку, в которой это происходит?

Comment: большое спасибо было замыкание я его нашел :) надо будет посмотреть как тему закрыть